# Running jacoco report where integration tests are in one code base and source code is in another code base

Tags: maven, jacoco

I recently started working on creating jacoco reports for maven projects including unit and integration tests and they seem to work out correctly. 
Now I have encountered a different scenario which I am not sure how to approach. 
I have one workspace which consists of integration test cases - application A, but the source code does not exist in the same workspace/code base. The source code which actually runs on invoking these integration test scripts are in a different workspace/code base - application B(they are invoked using rest api calls with the localhost urls. The jboss server is started for application B so that the localhost context is up) from the integration tests. 
The aim is to invoke these integration tests from application A, which in turn calls the source code of these tests in application B generating the jacoco report of the code coverage for application B.
I am not actually sure how to achieve this. 
Can someone provide some input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you actually have 2 different processes in your scenario:

- The "client" process that runs the integration tests and for which jacoco can be easily applied, but it's not what you need
- The "server" process that runs the actual JBoss server and executes the actual code.

Client process contacts the server via HTTP.

In this case, I'm afraid jacoco won't be able to provide a coverage for you *if you're running the tests from maven/gradle*, because jacoco instruments only bytecode on the running JVM. So you have to be "creative" here :)

I'll list here some possible approaches
*Disclaimer:* I haven't tried them though (didn't work with jboss/java ee), but maybe you'll be able to at least borrow some ideas

**The first approach** would be running the tests together with the application somehow, like its done for example in spring tests (I'm not sure whether JBoss provides similar capabilities).

The idea is simple:

- You run the integration test, it runs the jboss "embedded in the same jvm" and you can inject beans / EJB session beans into the test (like autowiring with spring).

The advantage of such a method is that you'll be able just to use jacoco maven plugin and it will instrument everything for you

I don't know how easy will be achieving this architecture technically, I know that recent jboss versions support embedded mode, So maybe you'll find [This link](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossEmbeddedASQuickstartAndRunnableExample) to be a useful foundation

**Another direction** is to take a look at [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org) project. They have some jacoco extension that probably will help, but I've never tried it.

**And the last approach** I can think of is running the jboss server with jacoco agent directly instead of relying on the build system that runs jacoco for you.

The idea here is to stream the results of covered server code into some file / tcp endpoint. So you run the jboss with `-javaagent:[yourpath/]jacocoagent.jar` and it starts streaming the results wherever you need it to stream. After the tests you should gather these results and prepare a report. You can find [Here](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) more information about this approach

Comment: Thank you so much Mark for that detailed explanation. Going over the approaches, I think the last approach of using the jacocoagent.jar maybe something that I can give it a try.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the jacocoagent.jar file location needs to be added as a JVM argument on the jboss server for application B(server). So would I have to setup any specific jacoco configuration in the sever application pom.xml or the client application pom.xml or both ? I see several options of using the "dump" goal and the "report-integration" or "report-aggregation" goal. But I do not think I have a lot of clarity on the jacoco set up steps for this specific scenario. Can you please advise?

Comment: It really depends on how exactly do you run the jboss. -javaagent option is a "general" option of jvm that allows running stuff before the "main" method. Jacoco uses this hook to perform a bytecode instrumentation on a set of given classes (for example you should be able to filter out classes that you don't want to produce a coverage for). So jboss can be run with java:exec plugin from maven (in this case case you should specify the javagent as plugin configuration), or via external script, etc

Comment: Hey Mark, I was able to generate the jacoco.exe for the integration tests run on the server code. but the report goal seems to fail, I tried "report-integration" , "report", "report-aggregate" but the report file does not get generated, The jacoco.exec got created in the parent project in the same folder as pom.xml, but is the report not generated due to the source classes of the code not being present in the same director?

Comment: I tried using mvn jacoco:report but it said skipping execution due to missing data. Not sure why that is, DO I need to pass any specific options in the mvn jacoco:report to get the report generated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: jacoco:report is a goal that builds a human-readable coverage report out of coverage information created during the test run and usually stored in jacoco.exec file. The presence of jacoco.exec file is crucial for report goal to run. You can customize the report goal in jacoco plugin definition so that it will include the jacoco.exec file. Take a look here: https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html